# Laravel Fullcalendar 5.5

Tags: php, laravel-5, fullcalendar

i'm trying to implement Laravel FullCalendar with help of (https://github.com/maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar)

[image]

My controller code -

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Calendar;
use App\Event;

class EventController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $events = [];
        $data = Event::all();
        if($data->count()) {
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                $events[] = Calendar::event(
                    $value->title,
                    true,
                    new \DateTime($value->start_date),
                    new \DateTime($value->end_date.' +1 day'),
                    null,
                    // Add color and link on event
                    [
                        'color' => '#f05050',
                        'url' => 'pass here url and any route',
                    ]
                );
            }
        }
        $calendar = Calendar::addEvents($events);
        return view('fullcalender', compact('calendar'));
    }
}
```

Blade File -

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('style')
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.2.7/fullcalendar.min.css"/>
@endsection

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Full Calendar Example</div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    {!! $calendar->calendar() !!}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection

@section('script')
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.2.7/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
{!! $calendar->script() !!}
@endsection
```

I m sharing calendar event creation code.

```
$calendar = \Calendar::addEvents($events) //add an array with addEvents
    ->addEvent($eloquentEvent, [ //set custom color fo this event
        'color' => '#800',
    ])->setOptions([ //set fullcalendar options
        'firstDay' => 1
    ])->setCallbacks([ //set fullcalendar callback options (will not be JSON encoded)
        'eventClick' => 'function() {
             showModal();
         }'
    ]);
```

everything work fine, but i need to open pophover (custom html) on click of event. as i had implemented same thing with JS fullcalendar (https://codepen.io/IsmiKin/pen/WbOeGw).

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I need to" is not a question, error message or problem statement. What have you researched about your requirement so far? What have you implemented (or tried to implement)? What are you stuck with? This is not a free research or write-my-code service, but we will help with specific issues.

Comment: let me share my research

Comment: Please do. We are waiting...

Comment: hey @ADyson, i had update a question

Comment: So I would guess you can recreate that eventRender callback with the "callbacks" section of your PHP? It looks like you just paste the Javascript into it?

Answer (score 1):

Just add eventRender to the setCallbacks() method. I assumed you are using bootstrap 4.

```
$calendar = Calendar::addEvents($e)->setCallbacks([
      'themeSystem' => '"bootstrap4"',
      'eventRender' => 'function(event, element) {
        element.popover({
          animation: true,
          html: true,
          content: $(element).html(),
          trigger: "hover"
          });
        }'
      ]);
```